# Is there a space efficient way to compute the gcd of high exponents?

Tags: biginteger, integer-overflow, exponentiation

Basically, I am writing a program that works with large integer values that overflow the cpp integer. I am trying to compute something like: `gdc(pow(a, b), c)` where `a ^ b` is the value overflowing the integer limit. Is there a way to do this where I don't have to rely on big integer libraries? If not, are there any recommended big integer libraries?

Comment: Do you need solution in `C++` or `Python`? You can do modular exponentiation `gcd(powmod(a, b, c), c)`, it doesn't need big integers. I'll write a simple small program for you if you tell me what language to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a property of [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) that `gcd(a, b) = gcd(a % b, b)`. Hence `gcd(pow(a, b), c) = gcd(pow(a, b) % c, c) = gcd(powmod(a, b, c), c)`, where `powmod()` is [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

In my C++ code below `PowMod()` is implemented using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) approach.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/6z9x16cax)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using Word = uint32_t;
using DWord = uint64_t;

Word GCD(Word a, Word b) {
    Word t = 0;
    while (b != 0) {
        t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}

Word PowMod(Word a, Word b, Word c) {
    Word r = 1;
    while (b != 0) {
        if (b & 1)
            r = (DWord(r) * a) % c;
        a = (DWord(a) * a) % c;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    Word const
        a = 2645680092U, b = 3562429202U, c = 3045001828U,
        powmod = PowMod(a, b, c), gcd = GCD(powmod, c);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b
        << ", c = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PowMod(a, b, c) = "
        << powmod << std::endl; // 592284924
    std::cout << "GCD(PowMod(a, b, c), c) = "
        << gcd << std::endl; // 1892
}
```

Output:

```
a = 2645680092, b = 3562429202, c = 3045001828
PowMod(a, b, c) = 592284924
GCD(PowMod(a, b, c), c) = 1892
```

which gives correct results, that can be verified through following simple Python program giving same result:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU9RDsIgDP3fKfpjxhJcNvdnnKfwAsBwI8ogDLN4@lmK2b82gT5e@/qof8fJzd22GetdiBDEPDjLwYo4FflRL1oPrKkKaeICPXSnYp3MU8MtvPS5AAyF9Lc5JTyjZi1cLsBIdIS24kBEelckEj@K4ACKhPIfN29R5d3KBAfJQWV2VAPSadkaIfN2r5g7Fa89tE3T5DVpTjBzZCV@vuSAs/CWhCVhRVjxvT8FMuhs3UDFZIKJrHOu9m4ZtHhs2wc)

```py
import random, math
random.seed(0)
bits = 32
while True:
    c = random.randrange(1 << (bits - 1), 1 << bits)
    a = random.randrange(1 << (bits - 1), 1 << bits) % c
    b = random.randrange(1 << (bits - 1), 1 << bits)
    pm = pow(a, b, c)
    gcd = math.gcd(pm, c)
    if gcd >= 1000:
        print('a =', a, ', b =', b, ', c =', c,
            ', powmod =', pm, ', gcd =', gcd)
        break
```

Output:

```
a = 2645680092 , b = 3562429202 , c = 3045001828 ,
    powmod = 592284924 , gcd = 1892
```

If you have GCC/CLang compiler, you can make Word to be 64-bit and DWord to be 128-bit, by changing following lines of code:

```cpp
using Word = uint64_t;
using DWord = unsigned __int128;
```

my code supports 32-bit inputs, but after this change you can have 64-bit inputs.

---

**Part 2**. Using large integer arithmetics library [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

If for some reason you have large input integers then you can use great library [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for large arithmetics (it supports integer, rational, floating point numbers).

This library has all [mathematical operations](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Arithmetic), including [modular exponentiation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation) (PowMod) and some [number theoretical](https://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions) functions (including GCD). Also this library is very popular and highly optimized.

In following code I do same things like in me code above, but using only GMP's functions. As an example I use 512-bit integers to show that it can accept large inputs (it can accept even millions of digits):

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow69900311#main.cpp)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main() {
    mpz_class const
        a("1953143455988359840868749111326065201169739169335107410565117106311318704164104986194255770982854472823807334163384557922525376038346976291413843761504166", 10),
        b("5126002245539530470958611905297854592859344951467500786493685495603638740444446597426402800257519403404965463713689509774040138494219032682986554069941558", 10),
        c("4396071968291195248321035664209400217968667450140674696924686844534284953565382985421958604880273584922294910355449271193696338132720472184903935323837626", 10);
    
    mpz_class powmod, gcd;
    // PowMod
    mpz_powm(powmod.get_mpz_t(), a.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t(), c.get_mpz_t()); // 1632164707041502536171492944083090257113212090861915134477312917063125646194834706890409016008321666479437224930114914370387958138698748075752168351835856
    // GCD
    mpz_gcd(gcd.get_mpz_t(), powmod.get_mpz_t(), c.get_mpz_t()); // 51842
    // Output
    std::cout << "PowMod = " << powmod.get_str() << std::endl
              << "GCD = " << gcd.get_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
PowMod = 1632164707041502536171492944083090257113212090861915134477312917063125646194834706890409016008321666479437224930114914370387958138698748075752168351835856
GCD = 51842
```

To use GMP library under Linux just install `sudo apt install libgmp-dev` and compile `clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -lgmp -o main main.cpp`.

Using GMP under Windows is a bit more tricky. One way is to build yourself [MPIR](https://mpir.org/downloads.html) library which is a Windows friendly clone of GMP. Another way is to install [MSYS](https://www.msys2.org/) and use prebuilt GMP from there [following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476068/941531) that I wrote in my other answer.

Comment: @patrickbies Please put a look at Part-2 of my answer above, I just posted it now. There I wrote how to use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) large integer library for same purposes of `GCD(powmod(a, b, c), c)` as I did for small integers in Part-1 of my answer. This Part-2 shall be used only if you have large inputs, i.e. if `a`, `b`, `c` are all large, for example 1024-bits. Click `Try it online!` link in Part-2 to see this library in action.